# Trying to optimize an aggregrate query for a big table in postgres

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, execution-plan

I'm trying to retrieve to get a top 3 of players from a big database containing their stats.
To do this i want to sum the kills they got in all of their games and select the 3 that have the most kills. Additionally I wanna count how many games they have played in total aswell. I'm only interested in games that are played on `server_number` 1 or 2, this is a field in the `map_history` table.

I'm using PostgreSQL 12.15.

There is a few tables that the needed data is stored in:

- `player_stats` contains the kills of a player in a game (1,038,160 rows)

```
                                                               Table "public.player_stats"
           Column           |       Type        | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                  | Storage  | Stats target | Description
----------------------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                         | integer           |           | not null | nextval('player_stats_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 playersteamid_id           | integer           |           | not null |                                          | plain    |              |
 map_id                     | integer           |           | not null |                                          | plain    |              |
 kills                      | integer           |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 kills_streak               | integer           |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 deaths                     | integer           |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 deaths_without_kill_streak | integer           |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 teamkills                  | integer           |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 teamkills_streak           | integer           |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 deaths_by_tk               | integer           |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 deaths_by_tk_streak        | integer           |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 nb_vote_started            | integer           |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 nb_voted_yes               | integer           |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 nb_voted_no                | integer           |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 time_seconds               | integer           |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 kills_per_minute           | double precision  |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 deaths_per_minute          | double precision  |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 kill_death_ratio           | double precision  |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 longest_life_secs          | integer           |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 shortest_life_secs         | integer           |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 death_by                   | jsonb             |           |          |                                          | extended |              |
 most_killed                | jsonb             |           |          |                                          | extended |              |
 name                       | character varying |           |          |                                          | extended |              |
 weapons                    | jsonb             |           |          |                                          | extended |              |
 death_by_weapons           | jsonb             |           |          |                                          | extended |              |
 combat                     | integer           |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 offense                    | integer           |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 defense                    | integer           |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
 support                    | integer           |           |          |                                          | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "player_stats_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "unique_map_player" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (playersteamid_id, map_id)
    "ix_player_stats_map_id" btree (map_id)
    "ix_player_stats_playersteamid_id" btree (playersteamid_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "player_stats_map_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (map_id) REFERENCES map_history(id)
    "player_stats_playersteamid_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (playersteamid_id) REFERENCES steam_id_64(id)
Access method: heap
```

- `map_history` contains the server the game was played on (10,974 rows)

```
                                                              Table "public.map_history"
    Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                 | Storage  | Stats target | Description
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id            | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('map_history_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 creation_time | timestamp without time zone |           |          |                                         | plain    |              |
 start         | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |                                         | plain    |              |
 end           | timestamp without time zone |           |          |                                         | plain    |              |
 server_number | integer                     |           |          |                                         | plain    |              |
 map_name      | character varying           |           | not null |                                         | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "map_history_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "unique_map" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (start, "end", server_number, map_name)
    "ix_map_history_end" btree ("end")
    "ix_map_history_map_name" btree (map_name)
    "ix_map_history_server_number" btree (server_number)
    "ix_map_history_start" btree (start)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "circle_external_events" CONSTRAINT "circle_external_events_map_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (map_id) REFERENCES map_history(id)
    TABLE "player_stats" CONSTRAINT "player_stats_map_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (map_id) REFERENCES map_history(id)
    TABLE "server_counts" CONSTRAINT "server_counts_map_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (map_id) REFERENCES map_history(id)
Access method: heap
```

- `steam_id_64` contains the steamid of the player (168,975 rows)

```
                                                             Table "public.steam_id_64"
   Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                 | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id          | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('steam_id_64_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 steam_id_64 | character varying           |           | not null |                                         | extended |              |
 created     | timestamp without time zone |           |          |                                         | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "steam_id_64_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "ix_steam_id_64_steam_id_64" UNIQUE, btree (steam_id_64)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "log_lines" CONSTRAINT "log_lines_player1_steamid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (player1_steamid) REFERENCES steam_id_64(id)
    TABLE "log_lines" CONSTRAINT "log_lines_player2_steamid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (player2_steamid) REFERENCES steam_id_64(id)
    TABLE "player_at_count" CONSTRAINT "player_at_count_playersteamid_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (playersteamid_id) REFERENCES steam_id_64(id)
    TABLE "player_blacklist" CONSTRAINT "player_blacklist_playersteamid_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (playersteamid_id) REFERENCES steam_id_64(id)
    TABLE "player_comments" CONSTRAINT "player_comments_playersteamid_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (playersteamid_id) REFERENCES steam_id_64(id)
    TABLE "player_flags" CONSTRAINT "player_flags_playersteamid_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (playersteamid_id) REFERENCES steam_id_64(id)
    TABLE "player_names" CONSTRAINT "player_names_playersteamid_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (playersteamid_id) REFERENCES steam_id_64(id)
    TABLE "player_optins" CONSTRAINT "player_optins_playersteamid_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (playersteamid_id) REFERENCES steam_id_64(id)
    TABLE "player_sessions" CONSTRAINT "player_sessions_playersteamid_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (playersteamid_id) REFERENCES steam_id_64(id)
    TABLE "player_stats" CONSTRAINT "player_stats_playersteamid_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (playersteamid_id) REFERENCES steam_id_64(id)
    TABLE "player_vip" CONSTRAINT "player_vip_playersteamid_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (playersteamid_id) REFERENCES steam_id_64(id)
    TABLE "player_watchlist" CONSTRAINT "player_watchlist_playersteamid_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (playersteamid_id) REFERENCES steam_id_64(id)
    TABLE "players_actions" CONSTRAINT "players_actions_playersteamid_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (playersteamid_id) REFERENCES steam_id_64(id)
    TABLE "steam_info" CONSTRAINT "steam_info_playersteamid_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (playersteamid_id) REFERENCES steam_id_64(id)
Access method: heap
```

The big issue is that the `player_stats` table contains 1m records and everything i tried is very slow.

The first basic query i came up with was:

```sql
select steam_id_64,
       count(ps.id)          as game_count,
       SUM(kills)            as total_kills
from map_history mh
         join player_stats ps on mh.id = ps.map_id
         join steam_id_64 s on ps.playersteamid_id = s.id
where server_number in (1, 2)
group by steam_id_64
order by SUM(kills) desc
limit 3;
```

The query plan for this one looks like this:

```
 Limit  (cost=173793.63..173793.63 rows=3 width=33) (actual time=7083.409..7091.846 rows=3 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=173793.63..174224.90 rows=172509 width=33) (actual time=7035.509..7043.943 rows=3 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (sum(ps.kills)) DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=122001.08..171563.98 rows=172509 width=33) (actual time=6002.603..6987.152 rows=155872 loops=1)
               Group Key: s.steam_id_64
               ->  Gather Merge  (cost=122001.08..167251.26 rows=345018 width=33) (actual time=6002.513..6841.477 rows=249394 loops=1)
                     Workers Planned: 2
                     Workers Launched: 2
                     ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=121001.05..126427.59 rows=172509 width=33) (actual time=5776.029..6432.059 rows=83131 loops=3)
                           Group Key: s.steam_id_64
                           ->  Sort  (cost=121001.05..121926.42 rows=370145 width=25) (actual time=5775.965..6258.428 rows=329919 loops=3)
                                 Sort Key: s.steam_id_64
                                 Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 11592kB
                                 Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 12240kB
                                 Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 13032kB
                                 ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=4083.07..77908.34 rows=370145 width=25) (actual time=126.612..1700.311 rows=329919 loops=3)
                                       Hash Cond: (ps.playersteamid_id = s.id)
                                       ->  Hash Join  (cost=372.86..73226.48 rows=370145 width=12) (actual time=64.083..1158.726 rows=329919 loops=3)
                                             Hash Cond: (ps.map_id = mh.id)
                                             ->  Parallel Seq Scan on player_stats ps  (cost=0.00..71719.98 rows=431698 width=16) (actual time=0.144..830.104 rows=345358 loops=3)
                                             ->  Hash  (cost=255.68..255.68 rows=9375 width=4) (actual time=63.644..63.655 rows=9396 loops=3)
                                                   Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 459kB
                                                   ->  Seq Scan on map_history mh  (cost=0.00..255.68 rows=9375 width=4) (actual time=46.478..56.450 rows=9396 loops=3)
                                                         Filter: (server_number = ANY ('{1,2}'::integer[]))
                                                         Rows Removed by Filter: 1560
                                       ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=2441.76..2441.76 rows=101476 width=21) (actual time=61.463..61.464 rows=56221 loops=3)
                                             Buckets: 262144  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11296kB
                                             ->  Parallel Seq Scan on steam_id_64 s  (cost=0.00..2441.76 rows=101476 width=21) (actual time=0.067..52.874 rows=168663 loops=1)
```

The only progress I booked was by moving one of the joins to execute after the limit by using a subquery:

```sql
select steam_id_64, game_count, total_kills
from (select playersteamid_id,
             count(ps.id) as game_count,
             SUM(kills)   as total_kills
      from map_history mh
               join player_stats ps on mh.id = ps.map_id
               join steam_id_64 s on ps.playersteamid_id = s.id
      where server_number in (1, 2)
      group by ps.playersteamid_id
      order by SUM(kills) desc
      limit 3) a
         join steam_id_64 s on a.playersteamid_id = s.id;
```

The plan for this is:

```
 Nested Loop  (cost=91770.43..91795.36 rows=3 width=33) (actual time=2405.398..2408.375 rows=3 loops=1)
   ->  Limit  (cost=91770.01..91770.02 rows=3 width=24) (actual time=2405.322..2408.274 rows=3 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=91770.01..91871.71 rows=40680 width=24) (actual time=2405.320..2408.271 rows=3 loops=1)
               Sort Key: (sum(ps.kills)) DESC
               Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
               ->  Finalize HashAggregate  (cost=90837.43..91244.23 rows=40680 width=24) (actual time=2319.009..2375.805 rows=155872 loops=1)
                     Group Key: ps.playersteamid_id
                     ->  Gather  (cost=81684.43..90227.23 rows=81360 width=20) (actual time=1849.188..2058.995 rows=278135 loops=1)
                           Workers Planned: 2
                           Workers Launched: 2
                           ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=80684.43..81091.23 rows=40680 width=20) (actual time=1737.755..1798.243 rows=92712 loops=3)
                                 Group Key: ps.playersteamid_id
                                 ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=4083.07..77908.34 rows=370145 width=12) (actual time=80.721..1362.415 rows=329919 loops=3)
                                       Hash Cond: (ps.playersteamid_id = s_1.id)
                                       ->  Hash Join  (cost=372.86..73226.48 rows=370145 width=12) (actual time=11.040..879.462 rows=329919 loops=3)
                                             Hash Cond: (ps.map_id = mh.id)
                                             ->  Parallel Seq Scan on player_stats ps  (cost=0.00..71719.98 rows=431698 width=16) (actual time=0.116..643.410 rows=345358 loops=3)
                                             ->  Hash  (cost=255.68..255.68 rows=9375 width=4) (actual time=10.762..10.764 rows=9396 loops=3)
                                                   Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 459kB
                                                   ->  Seq Scan on map_history mh  (cost=0.00..255.68 rows=9375 width=4) (actual time=0.045..7.396 rows=9396 loops=3)
                                                         Filter: (server_number = ANY ('{1,2}'::integer[]))
                                                         Rows Removed by Filter: 1560
                                       ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=2441.76..2441.76 rows=101476 width=4) (actual time=65.943..65.944 rows=56222 loops=3)
                                             Buckets: 262144  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8704kB
                                             ->  Parallel Seq Scan on steam_id_64 s_1  (cost=0.00..2441.76 rows=101476 width=4) (actual time=0.023..15.654 rows=56222 loops=3)
   ->  Index Scan using steam_id_64_pkey on steam_id_64 s  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=21) (actual time=0.029..0.029 rows=1 loops=3)
         Index Cond: (id = ps.playersteamid_id)
```

Is it possible to make this query faster? or should i look into something like materialized views?

Comment: What are your table and index definitions?

Comment: Please provide proper information for the performance question as instructed here: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3299/3684 Any reason you are still on Postgres 12? Please elaborate on this: *"I'm only interested in games that are played on `server_number` 1 or 2."* How many numbers are there?

Comment: I think this is as good as it gets. You are churning a lot of data. If you need that often and fast, consider materialized views that pre-aggregate the data.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link @ErwinBrandstetter, I've added the table definitions.

Currently there is only 4 servers so the server_number will range from 1 to 4.

Comment: Are you getting a benefit from the parallel execution?  You can try again with max_parallel_workers_per_gather=0 and see if that makes things better, or at least not much worse.  Also, increasing work_mem so that the sorts are done in memory can help (but probably not dramatically)